# Draw dynamic rectangle based on date co-ordinates

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I need to draw dynamic rectangles based on the **date co-ordinates**. In order to extract the x & y-axis, I need to do it from date.

So, far I tried 3 ways

1. chart.addPlotBand() this function is to draw dynamic plot bands. The problem is it will plot either on the x-axis or y-axis
   [1st Approach](http://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/rjxqm7d9/12/). 2nd problem is here I can't draw two plotbands with the dynamic width & co-ordinates.
2. This approach I tried with a chart.renderer though it works still it has some problems such as I need to find a way to pass dynamic width, X-Axis & Y-axis. The other problem is need to convert date coordinates to x & y coordinates.Lastly, the bar doesn't expand when we expand the browser screen. [2nd Approach](http://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/z6dc5kqt/24/)

   ```
   chart.renderer.rect(60, 40, 280, 50, 1)
      .attr({
        fill: '#FCFFC5',
         zIndex: 3,
         text: 'adasd'
     }).add();

   chart.renderer.label('Eco', 60, 40)
     .css({
      fontSize: '15pt',
      textAlign: 'center'
    })
       .attr({
          zIndex: 4,

        }).add();

   chart.renderer.rect(330, 40, 280, 50, 1)
    .attr({
      fill: '#04f9fe',
      zIndex: 3,

     }).add();
   ```
3. I tried with polygon but the problem is I don't have x & y coordinates. I need to extract from the date. Also not sure whether [3rd Approach](http://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/b2pLj9ot/14/) will work with date formats

THis is the main [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/tkajvdxp/8/) where I am exactly looking to draw rectangle based on the mentioned things

1)I have date co-ordinates which need to be converted in the x & y-axis.

2)If we have only first rectangle then it should dynamic take all the space in the header

Comment: I think the dataset is wrong because it has 4 x-axis coordinates

Comment: @MariosNikolaou In which approach?

Comment: As i can see from fiddle there is a json `keyDocumentData` which has 4 x-axis values

Comment: Actually some of the data I have removed. It is just the sample data

Comment: In the sample json file you have only 4 XAxis values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the second approach is the best. Below are my guidelines how to make it responsive and by using the data time format.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vfg51cey/

```
  if (chart.rectOne) {
    chart.rectOne.destroy();
  }
```

Checking if the custom rectangle element exists after each render keeps the rendering responsive.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Can you please explain the toPixels()  method

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can find the explanation here: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels